# How to get data from MySQL database to Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, communication

From my android app I want to get some data from my table containing two columns in my online MySQL database. Could someone explain me how to write a PHP script or something what I need that would respond to a call from my Android application by getting some values from my database and returning it to my app? And then how to call that function from my application and how to handle (save in my app) the returned data? HUGE HUGE THANKS in advance!

Comment: Nobody is going to write your code for you, show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well I didn't tried anything yet except I tried to analyze this example http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/connect-android-to-mysql-database-tutorial.8339/ but I don't understand how to make that PHP code respond to my HttpPost call from Android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a built-in MySQL connector for the `Android` framework, and even using an external `jar` for this is discouraged. The best way you can accomplish this is via a webservice in the remote server, so instead of sending direct MySQL queries to a database, you'd send a `HTTP POST` to the remote webserver (for instance, written in PHP, Python or whatever you want) and this would connect to the local database and make the query.

I think [this example](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/connect-android-to-mysql-database-tutorial.8339/) might help you.

Comment: I have already tried that example but I don't understand from where and how to call this PHP script. I know about using HttpPost in Android, but I don't know how to handle this in a PHP script. How to return the data from database to Android application?

Comment: You should have a remote server written in your favourite language (in this case, PHP) that would act as an intermediate between your Android app and the database. Thus, from your Android app you send some code to your remote server via a `HTTP POST` request, the server performs the operation for that code (for instance, extract some value from the database) and writes it via `echo` so your Android app can retrieve the value. This is the basic schema.

Comment: So, if I use the example you mentioned above, I just need to send the `HTTP POST` request to the server where that PHP script is located and then just directly read its output (print json_encode($rows))? Is this the right way?

Comment: No, in that script you would define what to do with that request. For example, you might add a `POST` entry called `code`, and when `code`'s value is `giveMeTheRows`, your PHP script would connect to your local database, get all the rows you need and just put them in the stdout (via `echo` or via `json_encode()`, for example).

Comment: And then I read that `echo` or `json_encode()` in my Android application, yes? And how to add a `POST` entry?

Comment: That's it. To send a `HTTP POST` request, follow this snippet: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: So in that PHP script I have to check if $_POST['id'] is the value I need and then do all the job and echo the data from database?

Comment: You can call it whatever you want, but if you send it like `code`, you'll have to collect it like `$_POST['code']`. So if you get that var and it has a specific meaning to you in your script, you can tell it to do whatever you need and return a response which you would later process as a response in your Android app.

Comment: Well, sorry for my dumbness and thanks for your patience! I think I got it and now it's clear for me. I'll try to do what I need now! HUGE THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

When you make the http request to the php script, you handle the request based on the method you sent, GET or POST.So for example

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

From there you do whatever server side queries to get the needed information. When you are done, simply echo the response back. I would recommend using JSON as the format as its easier to deal with.

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'data'=>$data));
```

Comment: What is this line for `$id=$_POST['id'];`?

Comment: To catch any data that you might want to send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class to write your own sqlite helper interface.

Try following some tutorials on Android's site [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Or follow a neat tutorial [here from vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).